# Cloud build is failing to connect to npm and install packages. Network error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, build-server

```
Step #0: [2/4] Fetching packages...    
Step #0: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

The retrying step happens X times until I cancel.
It worked once after 457s, but failed because this also happens inside docker containers, and there it is a timeout.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Think it is a network bug from Google. Started experiencing this today.

Does not happen locally.

Comment: If it is a bug: maybe create a support-case at Google?

Answer (score 1):

npm registry was [having a connection problem](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/bydjtj102gsn) at 10.28 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

```
“But it would be great with an issue tracker of some sorts? 
 Or a status page if anyone knows about it?”
```

Yes, visit [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/) to check status information on the services that are part of Google Cloud.
For third party softwares like NPM, you can check their respective status pages, for example - [this](https://status.npmjs.org/) for NPM.
Subsequently, you can also check [build logs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs), the next time you face an anomaly with Cloud Build..

Comment: Thanks alot for these status pages! I did watch the build logs and they were just saying network error or slowness. But I did not experience it locally, that was the funny business and why I wondered if it was something on Google side.

Or ar there any other build logs you are refering to?

Comment: That’s the same Cloud Build I was referring to, vonGohren, good probe work.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be a GCP issue and nothing on my side. It started working again now. But it would be great with an issue tracker of somesorts? Or a status page if anyone know about it?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the issue. All services were up. I found the solution and
I suspect the google cloud platform network (Idk the exact service). Just increase the network timeout. Also increasing the machine type might help.

`yarn install --prod --network-timeout 1000000`